# Why this docker file is not running with a shell script?

Tags: shell, docker

Now, I made a docker file named as (Dockerfile) as follows:

When I build this using the following command:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile .
```

I get the following output:

```
Step 1 : FROM ******.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/centos-base:7
 ---> 9ab68a0dd16a
Step 2 : COPY echo_hello.sh /echo_hello.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e7d541f5cf53
Step 3 : RUN bash /echo_hello.sh
 ---> Running in 4b5518faab28
hello world
hello world
.......
```

But, when I then begin to run it using the following command:

```
docker run -it d2cc33b16e8f
```

This doesn't happen and instead it shows me an error:

the command to run to start the application

Where am I going wrong in this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your Dockerfile to the following:

```
FROM *******.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/centos-base:7
COPY echo_hello.sh /echo_hello.sh
RUN chmod u+x /echo_hello.sh
CMD /echo_hello.sh
```

This page explains the Dockerfile instructions pretty well:

http://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/

Answer (score 0):

`RUN` commands are executed at build time (when you do a `docker build`). What you need is `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`. Either of these sets the executable that is run when the container starts (via `docker run`)

Your Dockerfile should look similar to what @Rezney has in his answer.